# Como chamar uma activity a partir de um click em um item de uma ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em que existe um `tablayout` e em umas das tabs uma lista expansiva.

Porem eu queria um método para que, quando clicar nas opções especificas da lista expansiva abra outra `activity` com suas respectivas características.

Estou iniciando na programação android e ainda tenho problemas em entender algumas coisas.

Comment: criar ou abrir? você poderia postar um exemplo ou parte do código do seu projeto?

Comment: creio que seja algo simples de resolver, intent deve resolver, mas preciso que poste o código ou um exemplo